# Joomla archive by year?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, archive

I posted this question before, but it got drowned and barely got any views so I figured I'd try one more time.

This seems like such a strange thing to not exist yet but I've been looking for ages. Is there an archive plug-in or component, or any way really, to simply sort the archive by year? All I want is to display columns for each year, with the year displayed above each column, containing a (clickable) list of archived titles. I'm using Joomla 2.5.

Anyone know how to do this? Whether it's through a plug-in/component or editing the existing archive code; don't care how, just want to get it done. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be an ideal solution and not too clean either, but I used [Monthly Archive](http://www.joomla357.com/demo/monthly-archive.html) and changed the getMonths() method in the monthlyarchiveclass to include this:

```
$byYear = array();
foreach($month_years_unique as $month_year){
    $year = explode('-',$month_year);
    $byYear[$year[1]] = array();
}

foreach($results_months as $result){
    $year   = $result['year'];
    $id = $result['id'];
    $byYear[$year] = array(
        $id => $result,
    );
}           

if(count($byYear) != 0){
    foreach($byYear as $year => $value){
        $html .= '<div class="archivecolumn"><h1>'.$year.'</h1>';
        $html .= '<ul class="itemlist">';
        foreach($value as $item){
            $cat = $this->getCatName($item['catid']);
            $link = 'index.php/' . $cat . '/' . $item['id'] . '-' . $item['alias'];
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$item['title'].'</a>';
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
} else {
    $html .= 'No archived works.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try these extensions:

[JExtBOX Article History](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists/24748) - 5$

Demo : http://demo.jextbox.com/

---

[Monthly Archive](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists/16207)

Demo: http://www.joomla357.com/demo/monthly-archive.html - ?$

---

[Mod LCA](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists/10731)

Demo: http://www.jonijnm.es/web/mod-lca.html - free

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out after a while. Eventually I took Monthly Archive and changed it so it would only sort by year (instead of by month).